# Citrix remote disconnect / Remote disconnect source

Tags: citrix, xenapp, terminal-services

Consider xen app server hosting published application. Is it possible to find out if the remote disconnect  was triggered by citrix or other source ?

Answer (score 1):

if it was disconnect by Citrix then it normally because of the idle timeout and if this is the case then there will be a event in the windows event stating that the session was disconnected because of idle timeout